# Generate output files from template file and csv data in python

Tags: python, xml, csv, elementtree

I need to generate xml files poulated with data from a csv file in python

I have two input files:

one CSV file named data.csv containing data like this:

```
ID  YEAR    PASS    LOGIN   HEX_LOGIN
14Z 2013    (3e?k<.P@H}l    hex0914Z    F303935303031345A
14Z 2014    EAeW+ZM..--r    hex0914Z    F303935303031345A
.......
```

One Template file named template.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SecurityProfile xmlns="security_profile_v1">
<year></year>
<security>
<ID></ID>
<login></login>
<hex_login></hex_login>
<pass></pass>
</security>
</SecurityProfile>
```

I want to get as many output files as lines in the csv data file, each output filed named YEAR_ID, with the data from the csv file in the xml fields:

Output files contentes:

Content of output file #1 named 2013_0950014z:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SecurityProfile xmlns="security_profile_v1">
<year>2013</year>
<security>
<ID>14Z</ID>
<login>hex0914</login>
<hex_login>F303935303031345A</hex_login>
<pass>(3e?k<.P@H}l</pass>
</security>
</SecurityProfile>
```

Content of output file #2 named 2014_0950014z:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SecurityProfile xmlns="security_profile_v1">
<year>2014</year>
<security>
<ID>14Z</ID>
<login>hex0914</login>
<hex_login>F303935303031345A</hex_login>
<pass>EAeW+ZM..--r</pass>
</security>
</SecurityProfile>
```

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Looks quite trivial to me - using `csv.DictReader` + standard string formating should be enough. What have you tried ?

Comment: So which bit are you struggling with?

Comment: At first I thought I needed something lke elementtree, so I was struggling with xml, but Burhan Khalid's solution looks googd to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you make changes the template? If so, I would do the following to make this a bit simpler:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SecurityProfile xmlns="security_profile_v1">
<year>{year}</year>
<security>
<ID>{id}</ID>
<login>{login}</login>
<hex_login>{hex_login}</hex_login>
<pass>{pass}</pass>
</security>
</SecurityProfile>
```

Then, something like this would work:

```
import csv

input_file_name = "some_file.csv" #name/path of your csv file
template_file_name = "some_file.xml" #name/path of your xml template
output_file_name = "{}_09500{}.xml"

with open(template_file_name,"r") as template_file:
    template = template_file.read()

with open(input_file_name,"r") as csv_file:
    my_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in my_reader:
        with open(output_file_name.format(row["YEAR"],row["ID"]),"w") as current_out:
            current_out.write(template.format(year=row["YEAR"],
                                              id=row["ID"],
                                              login=row["LOGIN"],
                                              hex_login=row["HEX_LOGIN"],
                                              pass=row["PASS"]))
```

If you can't modify the template, or want to process it as XML instead of basic string manipulation, then it's a bit more involved.

**EDIT:**

Modified answer to use `csv.DictReader` rather than csv.reader.

Fixed variable names opening input CSV file and writing the output. Removed 'binary' mode file operations.

Comment: Yes, I can change the template. That suits my needs! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

header = '<?xml version="1.0"?><SecurityProfile xmlns="security_profile_v1">\n'
footer = '\n</SecurityProfile>'
entry = '''<security>
              <ID>{0[ID]}</ID>
              <login>{0[LOGIN]}</login>
              <hex_login>{0[HEX_LOGIN]}</hex_login>
              <pass>{0[PASS]}</pass>
           </security>'''

rows = defaultdict(list)

with open('infile.csv') as f:
   reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')
   for item in reader:
      rows[reader['YEAR']].append(item)

for year,data in rows.iteritems():
   with open('{}.xml'.format(year), 'w') as f:
      f.write(header)
      f.write('<year>{}</year>\n'.format(year))
      for record in data:
          f.write(entry.format(record))
          f.write('\n')
      f.write(footer)
```